# Error when Obfuscate IOS Project using IOS-Class-Guard - xcode 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, obfuscation

I using `ios-class-guard` to obfuscate my ios project. It work at xcode 9 , ios sdk 10.2.
But when i update xcode to version 9.0 and run `bash obfuscate_project` - it 's ok , but i can't build project because   `ios-class-guard` has encrypted the frameword of ios sdk.
Sample:

```
insertObject  
removeObjectAtIndex  
addObject  
removeLastObject  
replaceObjectAtIndex
```

in `NSMutableArray`
`dictionary` in `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]`
Any help,please.

Comment: You might wish to look at [PPiOS-Rename](https://github.com/preemptive/PPiOS-Rename). It's a fork of ios-class-guard that fixes many issues and has been maintained for new versions of Xcode/iOS. (Full disclosure: I work for PreEmptive Solutions, who make PPiOS-Rename.)